# Differences Between Microcontroller and Device Controller

Tags: controller, microcontroller

Is a device controller also a microcontroller with more functions? I know device controller has input and output ports for external device communication but how about communication between device controller and cpu?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698158/what-is-the-difference-between-microprocessor-and-microcontroller help? It's above my paygrade...

Comment: Device controller is a concept that goes way back in computer hardware history, before any microcontrollers were available. Device controller could be all HW logic circuits, or (the typical modern version) a custom processor with RAM, (EEP)ROM (or flash), and firmware.  A microcontroller is a processor-plus-periperals IC that can be used for almost any application. A microcontroller is often the guts of an embedded system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Device Controller receives the data from a connected device and stores it temporarily in some special purpose registers (i.e. local buffer) inside the controller. Then it communicates the data with a Device Driver . For each device controller there is an equivalent device driver which is the standard interface through which the device controller communicates with the Operating Systems through Interrupts. Device controller is a hardware whereas device driver is a software. The controller's job is to convert the serial bit stream to block bytes and perform any error correction necessary.